# How to set the PlotWidget Tick Color in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I'm trying to set the style the axis of a pyqtgraph.PlotWidget plotting area. I'm using:

```
font = QFont()
font.setPointSize(14)
font.setBold(True)
font.setWeight(75)

myPlotWidget.getAxis('left').setPen('b')
myPlotWidget.getAxis('left').setFont(font)
```

and I don't understand why the tick label color is not blue while the axis, grid and axis labels are.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use [`AxisItem.setTextPen()`](https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/graphicsItems/axisitem.html#pyqtgraph.AxisItem.setTextPen) explicitly:

```
self.graphWidget.getAxis('left').setTextPen('b')
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked fine. I guess the name is not obvious. I skimmed through that doc several times and couldn't figure that's what I needed.

Comment: Actually, I didn't know about it until 10 minutes ago, I just did a `print(dir(self.graphWidget.getAxis('left')))` and looked for anything starting with "set" and containing "pen" ;-)